# How to clear the GridView column greater than index 1

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

how to clear the GridView column greater than index 1.

`grdview.Columns.Clear()` will clear all columns, but i need to clear the columns greater than index 1

Answer (score 3):

You can use following code:

```
while(grid.Columns.Count > 2)
{
    Grid.Columns.RemoveAt(grid.Columns.Count - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're working with ASP.NET this will do. However, I would like to know why you want to remove the column. I could give you a better solution.

```
foreach(DataGridColumn col in vGrid.Columns)
{
     col.Visible = false;
}

vGrid.Columns[0].Visible = true;
vGrid.Columns[1].Visible = true;
```

or if you are using a template field

```
foreach(TemplateField col in vGrid.Columns)
{
    col.Visible = false;
}

vGrid.Columns[0].Visible = true;
vGrid.Columns[1].Visible = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (i = 2; i < gridView.Columns.count; i ++)
{
   gridView.Columns[i].Remove();
}
```

Correction

```
    while(gridView.Columns.count>2)
    {
    gridView.Columns.RemoveAt(2);
    //Or gridView.Columns.RemoveAt(gridView.Columns.Count -1);
    }
```

Comment: The problem with this is that after removing the column at index 2, the column which *was* at index 3 will now be at index 2. Unless I'm mistaken, that means you'll get an "Index out of bounds" exception.

Comment: I don't think that one will get an "Index out of bounds" exception, as the gridView.Columns.count is reevaluated each round. But many columns just will not be deleted (about half of them).

Answer (score 1):

I am no C# programmer, but I assume that as in Delphi (same language architect) collections are 0 based. therefore

```
for (i = gridView.Columns.count - 1; i > 1; i --)
{
   gridView.Columns[i].Remove();
}
```

If you remove from 2 to gridView.Columns.count - 1 then you will not remove all columns, as they get shifted when a column is removed, i.e. after the first remove of column two, the column that was third is now second, but the next column removed will be the third (i = 3).

Alternative:

```
while (gridView.Columns.Count > 2) 
{

   gridView.Columns[gridView.Columns.Count - 1].Remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

go with the loop like

```
for (i = 2; i < grdview.columns.count; i ++)
{
   grdview.columns[2].remove();
}
```

It is untested code. please check it.

Comment: This will work. Yet removing columns(2) will always cause the additional columns to be shifted down, which makes this costly.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to hide columns rather than to remove, because removing an element of enumeration causes the enumerator to be reseted so you need to do an addition operation to consider such behavior, IMO.

```
using System.Linq;

GridView1.Columns
    .OfType<DataControlField>()
    .Where(c => GridView1.Columns.IndexOf(c) > 1)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(c => c.Visible = false);
```

or

```
foreach(var c in GridView1.Columns
                              .OfType<DataControlField>()
                              .Where(c => GridView1.Columns.IndexOf(c) > 1))
{
    c.Visible = false;
}
```